# How to search history of commits with regex in TortoiseSVN

Tags: regex, svn, tortoisesvn

Few weeks ago, I started working with `TortoiseSVN`.

For a long time, everything was going well. I was using only basic commands:

```
add
commit
update
merge
```

Now, I realised that somone did big mess in repository what made our build failed. I try to find a commit, which caused that.

Someone, in our code, added few chars to name of directory, let's say it was:

```
"myname"
```

and after this change it was:

```
"mynameblah"
```

This change could be done only in few files (3-4 files).

I have no idea how many comitts ago it happend.

I know, I can go thorugh every single commit and for each suspicious file check commits history. It would take a lot of time, so I would like to ask, is there any easier way to find it?

I use

```
TortoiseSVN 1.8.4, Build 24972 - 64 Bit
Subversion 1.8.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would search the CURRENT version of all files for the problem text. Then, once you find the problem FILES, you can use the "blame" command to figure out when it happened (and whodunit). Using TortoiseSVN, this gives you a nice colorized GUI window with the latest version of the file on the right, and next to each line on the left is the revision number and user who last changed the line. Hovering over this information even provides a commit comment.